# How can my browser be hijacked on a fresh Linux installation?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser

This just happened to me and frankly its a little weird. I am running Manjaro Linux using their stock Firefox browser.

Occasionally, as I search I will get hijacked by a `chillcardiac` URL that leads to a “Mozilla you’re the lucky winner!” page. This occurs when I search through the bar without visiting DuckDuckGo and manually searching.

The only plugins I have installed are:

- Lastpass
- DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials
- Adnauseum

What could be causing this? All of these addons were downloaded from the official Mozilla extensions page.

Doing some more research it appears to be hijacking domains that don't exist. I can repeatedly get it to reproduce by typing `github.cm` in the browser.

Comment: It's not that github.cm is a domain that doesn't exist.These type of malicious/garbage sites are very common. They register domain names that are typos of popular sites. I'm sure they get a lot of traffic from people doing exactly what you did without realizing it.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cm): _.cm is the country code top-level domain for Cameroon._

Comment: I don't have enough info to give it as an anwser but I'm almost positive this is because you're using your ISPs DNS servers and those servers are malicious. Try setting your DNS to 8.8.8.8 and see if it still occures.

Comment: @jdwolf - Nah, github.cm is just a malicious site. If you go to it in your browser the same will happen (not recommending that you actually do that though).

Comment: Yes it would seem I jumped the gun and thought it was a browser/dns hijacking. Indeed, CURLing it gives the same redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a case of browser/DNS hijacking. What's happening in your case is what is referred to as **Typosquatting**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting):

> **Typosquatting**
>
> Typosquatting, also called URL hijacking, a sting site, or a fake URL,
>   is a form of cybersquatting, and possibly brandjacking which relies on
>   mistakes such as typos made by Internet users when inputting a website
>   address into a web browser. Should a user accidentally enter an
>   incorrect website address, they may be led to any URL (including an
>   alternative website owned by a cybersquatter).
>
> The typosquatter's URL will usually be one of five kinds, all similar
>   to the victim site address (e.g. example.com):
>
> - A common misspelling, or foreign language spelling, of the intended site: exemple.com
> - A misspelling based on typos: examlpe.com
> - A differently phrased domain name: examples.com
> - A different top-level domain: example.org
> - An abuse of the Country Code Top-Level Domain (ccTLD): example.cm by using .cm, example.co by using .co, or example.om by using .om. A
>     person leaving out a letter in .com in error could arrive at the fake
>     URL's website.
>
> Once in the typosquatter's site, the user may also be tricked into
>   thinking that they are in fact in the real site, through the use of
>   copied or similar logos, website layouts or content. Spam emails
>   sometimes make use of typosquatting URLs to trick users into visiting
>   malicious sites that look like a given bank's site, for instance.

You'll find a lot of these sites with the names of popular sites (like github in your case) but using the .cm domain instead of .com

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cm):

> .cm is the country code top-level domain (ccTLD) for Cameroon.
>   ......
>   ......
>   In a report published in December 2009 by McAfee, "Mapping the Mal Web - The world's riskiest domain", .cm was reportedly the riskiest domain in the world, with 36.7% of the sites posing a security risk to PCs. It is widely assumed that malicious domain programmers rely on inadvertent misspellings of well-trafficked websites ending in ".com" to lure unsuspecting users to their domains

And just to verify that it is not actually any problem with your browser or DNS, enter a gibberish address into your browser like http://alksfjlsasdfkanefiassdofweksfflasd.com and see that it doesn't redirect to a similarly malicious-type site.